# How to get my navigation bar to be red all the time?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I made my navigation bar change red in my values-21/styles.xml but there are times when it changes back to black, like when I open my keyboard or when my LoginActivity (the default one created from Activity picker when creating a new Activity) is attempting to login by showing the ProgressBar.
Here's my code for styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Main theme colors -->
            <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#F44336</item>
            <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#B71C1C</item>
            <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_red</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#F44336</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <!-- Main theme colors -->
            <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#F44336</item>
            <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#B71C1C</item>
            <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_red</item>
            <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#F44336</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```